# Android Webview won't load Javascript script of HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm currently building an Android App that uses a Webview to show a HTML site that has a javascript script in it. I use the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG, "-----> Starting HowItWorksActivity");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_how_it_works);
    WebView howItWorksView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.howItWorksView);
    WebSettings settings = howItWorksView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    howItWorksView.loadUrl("http://some_url/faq_de.html");
}
```

Where the html page looks like the following:

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
</head>
 (...)
 <h1>Some Text </h1>
 <script src="getmoretext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 (...)
</body>
```

In the Browser, this works perfectly fine, however the webview doesn't show the part that is created by the getmoretext script....

I have JavaScript and DomStorage enabled in the webview.

Any ideas?

Comment: PS: you don't need `type="text/javascript"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this line of code:

```
howItWorksView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())
```

Comment: Still don't work